# Azure DevOps: publish self-contained .net Core app with Chocolatey

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, chocolatey, self-contained

I need to create a self-contained .net core (3.1 in my case) app and to pack & publish using chocolatey so it can be installed and used.

I'm using Azure DevOps and have a feed on my own where I'm supposed to publish the chocolatey package.

The objective is to do this in the build pipeline, so, among other tasks I have:

- dotnet publish task: creates the self-contained executable
- chocolatey pack task: creates the .nupkg from a very simplistic .nuspec (only mandatory fields) I created.

My current problem is that the .nupkg file created contains always the project files and not the executable generated.

To try and work around it I even made the chocolatey pack's task work directory the same as the dotnet publish's task output one.

[image]

[image]

What am I missing? Is there another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tests I realized that the chocolatey pack will "pack" all files that in exist in the same folder as the ".nuspec". Not sure this is because I don't set anything on tool.

Basically, my solution was to copy my ".nuspec" file to the folder where my executable was.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps: publish self-contained .net Core app with Chocolatey

It depends on whether you include the contained executable file in your `.nuspec` file.

If we include the contained executable file in the `.nuspec` file, chocolatey will create the `.nupkg` include the contained executable file, like:

```
  <files>
    <file src="IngestCanonicLtesConsole\ContainedExecutable.exe" target="Tools\ContainedExecutable.exe" />
  </files>
```

We could add this contained executable file in the package:

[image]

So, if we are only include the mandatory fields without the `<files>contained executable </files>`, it will not include the contained executable file.

Besides, we need to include the contained executable file in the `.nuspec` file, we could change the output of the dotnet build to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\IngestCanonicLtesConsole`, so that we could use the relative path in the `.nuspec` file.

Please check the document [.nuspec reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec) for some more details.

Comment: I don't want to do this because the folder where the exe will be is a folder created in the azure devops agent and not even dreamed of existence before that. So this solution for me is as last resort.